# magento2 what exactly purpose of Factory class?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, compiler, code-generation, factory

From this [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/factories.html) Factories are special objects that have only one purpose: to create an instance of one non-injectable class or interface
non-injectable object are Objects that cannot be instantiated by the object manager. 
this `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`
is a factory class that really exist in vendor/magento/catalog directory

why we should use this function instead of inject directly `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` in constructor , and why `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` is a none-injectable class because from this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html) it is not instance of entity to provide or a model representing a database entity it is a collection of models

and another question is 
why `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory` already exist in vendor directory because from [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html) factories are an automatically generated class type. Factory classes do not need to be explicitly defined

Answer (score 6):

In general you use factories to instantiate non-injectable objects, like the cms page object. Some objects require user input to instantiate so you cannot inject them via the constructor. `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` is **not** one of those cases.

Factories are usually auto-generated, in the sense that, if you don't define one yourself, magento will auto-generate one for you:

```
if (!class_exists($className)) {
        return Generator::GENERATION_ERROR != $this->_generator->generateClass($className);
    }
```

And this answers your question about why you **should** use the Factory approach here. If you want to add a **common behaviour** for a certain collection, you have the chance to use your own Factory and easily modify the default behaviour.

But you can also inject `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` in the constructor if you want to. This is not a case of a non-injectable object. It will still work, but it is not recommended.

Comment: thank u for your answer , as you mention If I want to add a common behaviour for a certain collection Factories are good , but can give an example for it , for example in my case what is the benefit of using \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory over 
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection

Comment: @aligh in your case I can't think of a benefit of using factories